# How to Execute Google App Script API Function from another Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Google App Script AAA and deployed it as "API Executable" that runs as me, and then created a second Google App Script BBB that runs as the user accessing the web app.

The goal is to get the user email using script BBB and then pass that as a parameter to AAA to generate a Google Drive folder with the email as the folder name.

I cannot get the syntax correct to execute the function in AAA from BBB.

I am only using Google App Script. Examples I found are with using Java, or Python, etc, but I would like to do with within the Google App Script.

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve]. Provide [mcve]

Comment: To call your Web App AAA, you must make an HTTPS Request from file BBB with `UrlFetchApp(url)` to the published url of the AAA Web App.  [Link to fetch documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en#fetchurl,-params)  In file AAA you must have either a `doGet()` or `doPost()` function.  Those are reserved function names that are simple triggers, or event handlers that watch for the GET or POST request being made to the url of the published web app, and then run if a request is detected.  If you already have that then post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App BBB, pass the email address as a URL parameter to [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?hl=en#fetchurl):

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://address/of/appAAA?email=' + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
```

In App AAA, parse the email parameter within the `doGet()` function:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var email = e.parameter.email;
  // Do something with the email.
}
```

For more about the values passed to `doGet()` in the `e` Event object, [see here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters).